# Some suggestion for career in data science or predictive modeling

Tags: education, beginner, career

I am looking to choose my career in the area of decision science or predictive modeling and I am aware that this is kind of opinion based but I would like to have some suggestion from experts that I can use it to build my career in correct path. What are the tools should I know like R, SAS or any other. What are the thinks I should know to work in a data science or machine learning or predictive modeling. For me I am having problem in identifying steps that I should follow. Please suggest me some steps to follow.

Comment: A major point of clarification is whether you want to be in Academia or Industry. Both have radically different flavors about what is used, how it's used, and end goals.

Answer (score 5):

First of all I should say you question probably is an off-topic and will be closed soon.

**Discussed at this SE site**

Anyway I can target you to similar questions discussed at this SE site already:

- [Statistics + Computer Science = Data Science?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/808/statistics-computer-science-data-science)
- [Starting my career as Data Scientist, is Software Engineering experience required?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/739/starting-my-career-as-data-scientist-is-software-engineering-experience-require)

**Cross Validated SE**

A set of relevant questions at Cross Validated Stack Exchange:

- https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/careers

**Data scientist map**

This is good infographics of data science knowledge you might need to start a career ([Link to image](http://pennlio.files.wordpress.com/2013/09/roadtodatascientist1.png)):

[image: This is good infographics of data science knowledge you might need to start a career]

**Careers SE**

Also, simple "data scientist" querying of Careers SE site 
http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=data+scientist&location= will lead you to the following knowlege "tags":

- [R](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/tag/r)
- [bigdata](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/tag/bigdata)
- [data-visualization](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/tag/data-visualization)
- [hadoop](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/tag/hadoop)
- [mapreduce](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/tag/mapreduce)
- [scala](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/tag/scala)
- [python](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/tag/python)
- [matlab](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/tag/matlab)

etc.